# How can I change the scrollbar separator color in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: vscode scrollbar]

Need to change this color, its not one of the options provided for scrollbar theming. Is it hiden someplace else?

```
Scroll Bar Control
scrollbar.shadow: Scroll Bar shadow to indicate that the view is scrolled.
scrollbarSlider.activeBackground: Slider background color when active.
scrollbarSlider.background: Slider background color.
scrollbarSlider.hoverBackground: Slider background color when hovering.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`settings.json`:

```
"editor.overviewRulerBorder": false
```

Answer (score 4):

To change the colour of the separator, you can add this to `settings.json`:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorOverviewRuler.border": "#191C22"
}
```